# Browsing directories on remote linux server in C

Tags: c, ssh, dirent.h

On a local computer you can make use of the dirent.h library in C to browse files and folders. How would you do this on a remote linux computer? Would you pipe the readdir() commands through an ssh connection? I would like to achieve this without using any non-standard libraries.

Comment: AFIK you can mount the remote Linux computer disk to your local machine using NFS.So no need of any major change in your code.

Comment: Is `popen("sftp somemachine", "rw")` acceptible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use an SSH library like `libssh`.

  - http://api.libssh.org/stable/
- It includes an API for `SFTP` and `SCP` which are the file manipulation components of SSH.

  - http://api.libssh.org/stable/group__libssh__sftp.html
- There is a tutorial available here:

  - http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_sftp.html

There is example code for "Listing the contents of a directory" in that linked page.

> I would like to achieve this without using any non-standard libraries.

That just isn't feasible. While the libraries included in your Linux distribution (including source header files and directly linkable blobs) probably *do* include `libssh` owing to its ubiquity, it isn't "standard" because the C standard library doesn't mention SSH/SFTP (or even have a file-system API!) nor does POSIX.

SSH (and SFTP) is a relatively recent protocol - it was only created in 1995 and didn't see wide adoption until the late-1990s (people were still using `rlogin`, `rsh`, standard FTP, or even TELNET) - it's predated by FTP, HTTP, SMTP, and SSL/TLS.

(Remember C is very minimal - my perception is that it's a language used to manipulate and iterate over memory - everything else, even syscalls, are not part of the C standard - which is why you can compile C to JavaScript, for example, you just can't do anything fun because you can't syscall from JavaScript)

Comment: @Joshua If you mean by reimplementing an SSH client using BSD sockets *and* reimplementing your own crypto code - more like _person-centuries_ than _person-years).

Comment: Having read huge chunks of the putty code, my assessment is a handful of years will suffice.

Comment: @Joshua I've reworded my answer :)